How to efficiently run a large language model with a 60k+ token context window across multiple GPUs?
I'm working with a large language model (LLM) that requires a large context window of 60,000 to 70,000 tokens for my application. My setup includes five GPUs, with three 16GB GPUs and two 8GB GPUs. I've encountered several issues with GPU memory management and model partitioning for such a large input size and would appreciate advice on best practices or specific techniques to handle this scenario.
Details:
My setup includes a mix of GPUs: three with 16GB of memory and two with 8GB.
I’m trying to manage memory and efficiently partition the model across these GPUs, ideally to maximize throughput without running into memory issues.
Currently, I am experiencing out-of-memory (OOM) errors, particularly when managing such a large token input.
The input cannot be chunked into smaller parts, as it's a single continuous input for the LLM to process.
Questions:
What are some strategies to partition the model and input across GPUs in a mixed-memory environment?
Are there specific techniques or libraries (like Hugging Face’s transformers) that can help manage memory allocation across GPUs for such large input sizes?
Would model parallelism, pipeline parallelism, or a combination be the best approach here? How should I structure this setup to avoid OOM errors?
Any tips on fine-tuning GPU allocation, such as offloading parts of the model or using CPU-GPU memory transfer, while keeping performance stable?
Any guidance or experience with similar setups would be greatly appreciated!
